# Third level menu nav in bootstrap 3 rtl

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav, right-to-left

I use bootstrap 3 in my site and it's rtl direction.
I want to have third level menu nav in my site
I try to use SmartMenus Bootstrap Addon (Navbar) 
It works very well if it (ltr)
but as my site is rtl the (SmartMenus Bootstrap Addon) broken,
it does not work as it ought to be.
How can I use SmartMenus rtl without causeing any problems.
OR if any one know any better solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Second level</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                   </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks but this is a second level.and my question about third level.thanks again